# How can I make a cell change colour every x seconds?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am working on a document on google sheets and I want it to look nice, this code really is unimportant but it would great to know how to do it, as every bit I learn anyways, can help in the future.

Something a bit more technical could be 1 cell changes to a certain colour, then the other cell identifies that that cell has changed colour so it also changes colour, and it keeps going until it loops on the last cell (to kind of create a rainbow effect).

Please remember though, a lot of conditional formatting is unavailable in google docs sheets and you can't use macros, you have to use Google Sheet Script.

Comment: This is actually what Google uses to demo the [`flush()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush()) method. Mix a `Utilities.sleep(1000)` in there and you can watch your sheet blink nice and pretty. Problem is, though, if you want this to be on *all  the time*, you will very, very quickly hit the execution time limit for scripts.

Comment: To have a script respond to changes in a background color, you can use [`getBackground()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground), and then `setBackground()` in turn. Doing this over a spreadsheet of any significant size is also going to pretty quickly hit usage limits though.

Comment: @Altigraph can you not set a cooldown so that it stops after x amount of seconds and then carries on? So that it doesn't hit usage limit?

Comment: If you're doing it from the server side, you would set a time trigger which repeats e.g. every 5 minutes. Cooper's invoking it from the user-side is definitely a better way to go about it if you really need to, though more complicated to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Change color every x seconds**

Code.gs:

```
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('MyTools')
  .addItem('Show Sidebar', 'showTimerSideBar')
  .addToUi();
}

function showTimerSideBar()
{
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('datatimer').setTitle('Color Timer');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function changeData(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('ColorChange');
  var rg=sh.getRange('A1:A10');
  var colorA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var n=new Date();
  var tmr=Utilities.formatDate(n, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss")
  var rObj={color:colorA[Math.floor(Math.random()*colorA.length)][0],timer:tmr};
  ss.toast(Utilities.formatString('timer: %s color: %s', rObj.timer,rObj.color));
  return rObj;
}

function saveData(dObj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  var lr=sh.getLastRow();
  sh.getRange(lr+1,1).setValue(dObj.timer);
  sh.getRange(lr+1,2).setBackground(dObj.color);
}

function setA1(color) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('ColorChange');
  var rg=sh.getRange('A1');
  rg.setBackground(color);
}
```

datatimer.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <style>
      #my_block{border:2px solid black;background-color:rgba(0,150,255,0.2);padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;}
      #conv_block{border: 1px solid black;padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;}
      .bttn_block{padding:2px 5px 0px 0px;}
      .sndr_block {border:1px solid rgba(0,150,0,0.5);background-color:rgba(150,150,0,0.2);margin-bottom:2px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    <div id="my_block" class="block form-group">
      <div class="sndr_block">
        <div id="myClock" style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;"></div>
        <br />Timer Duration(seconds):
        <br /><input id="txt1" type="text" size="4" class="action"/>
        <select id="sel1" onChange="loadTxt('sel1','txt1');">
        </select>
        <div id="cntdiv"></div>
        <br /><strong>Timer Controls</strong>
        <div class="bttn_block"><input type="button" value="Start" name="startShow" id="startShow" onClick="startmytimer();changeData();" class="red" /></div>
        <div class="bttn_block"><input type="button" value="Stop" name="stopTimer" id="stopTimer" class="red" /></div>
        <div class="bttn_block"><input type="button" value="Single Ping" name="changedata" id="chgData" class="red" onClick="changeData();" /></div>
        <div class="bttn_block"><input type="button" value="Red" name="setA1Red" id="setRed" class="red" onClick="setA1('#ff0000');" /></div>
        <div class="bttn_block"><input type="button" value="Green" name="setA1Green" id="setGreen" class="green" onClick="setA1('#00ff00');" /></div>
      </div>
      <div id="btn-bar">
        <br /><input type="button" value="Exit" onClick="google.script.host.close();" class="green" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
    <script>
    var idx=1;
    var myInterval='';
    var cnt=0;
      $(function() {
        var select = document.getElementById('sel1');
        select.options.length = 0; 
        for(var i=1;i<61;i++)
        {
          select.options[i-1] = new Option(i,i * 1000);
        }
        select.selectedIndex=4;
        $('#startTimer').click(startmytimer);
        $('#stopTimer').click(stopTimer);
        $('#txt1').val(String(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value));
        startTime();
      });

      function startTime(){
        var today = new Date();
        var h = today.getHours();
        var m = today.getMinutes();
        var s = today.getSeconds();
        m = checkTime(m);
        s = checkTime(s);
        document.getElementById('myClock').innerHTML =
        h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
        var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
      }

      function checkTime(i){
        if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
        return i;
      }

      function startmytimer(){
        document.getElementById('cntdiv').innerHTML='<strong>Timer Started:</strong> ' + document.getElementById('myClock').innerHTML;
        myInterval=setInterval(changeData, Number($('#txt1').val()));
      }

      function stopTimer(){
        document.getElementById('cntdiv').innerHTML='Timer Stopped';
        clearInterval(myInterval);
      }

      function loadTxt(from,to){
        document.getElementById(to).value = document.getElementById(from).value;
      }

      function exportData() {
        google.script.run.saveData(cA);
      }

      function changeData(){
        $('#txt1').css('background','#ffffcc');
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(rObj){
          updateDisplay(rObj.timer);
          saveData({timer:rObj.timer,color:rObj.color});
          $('#txt1').css('background','#ffffff');
        })
        .changeData();
      }

      function updateDisplay(t){
        $('#txt1').css('background','#ffffff');
        document.getElementById('cntdiv').innerHTML='<strong>Timer Running:</strong> Count= ' + ++cnt + ' <strong>Time:</strong> ' + t;
      }

      function setA1(color) {
        console.log(color);
        google.script.run.setA1(color);
      }

      function saveData(dObj) {
        google.script.run.saveData(dObj);
      }
     console.log('My Code');
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Current Colors: (ColorChange Sheet)

[image]

Data Sheet:

[image]

Timer Sidebar:

[image]

I modified an existing script to provide you with this example.  So there may be other unrelated scripts in here.  Feel free to modify it to fit your specific needs.