# Is there a function to get a range and paste past the last row in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got the temperature of some cities via API that is refreshed every day in a google sheet. I would like to make an evolution chart to see how each city's temperature is evolving. For that, I am trying to write a script that copies the range of cells where the temperature appears and paste it every day to the last row.

This is the data I get in the same cells every day:

```
2019-06-11  London  11.17
2019-06-11  Madrid  16.51
2019-06-11  Paris   14.02
2019-06-11  Berlin  18.45
2019-06-11  Brussels    16.19
2019-06-11  Amsterdam   16.76
2019-06-11  Rome    25.97
2019-06-11  Zagreb  23.95
2019-06-11  Athens  26.16
2019-06-11  Lisbon  15.21
2019-06-11  Ljubljana   22.51
2019-06-11  Frankfurt   17.82

`enter code here`function saveData() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Temperaturaactualizada');
 var date = sheet.getRange(1, 5, 12, 3);
 date.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1, 12));

}
```

This would just copy that range and paste there, it does not append the rows day after day so I can get in a way that I can visualize it.

```
26-05-2019  London  21
26-05-2019  Madrid  28
26-05-2019  Paris   20
26-05-2019  Berlin  20
26-05-2019  Brussels    18
26-05-2019  Amsterdam   18
26-05-2019  Rome    19
26-05-2019  Zagreb  25
26-05-2019  Athens  26
26-05-2019  Lisbon  22
26-05-2019  Ljubljana   19
26-05-2019  Frankfurt   20
27/05/2019  London  16,81
27/05/2019  Madrid  26,36
27/05/2019  Paris   18,37
27/05/2019  Berlin  17,77
27/05/2019  Brussels    17,82
27/05/2019  Amsterdam   15,9
```

This way

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I originally used the code for this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56510215/7215091) to take samples of Google Finance tags to record some changing data.  It should be pretty easy to modify for your needs.